# Can I change my Facebook login email?

Tags: facebook

My wife and I have been "sharing" a facebook account under my name, and we're finally going to get her her own account. The problem is that the facebook "login" email is really *her* email account.

Is there a way to change the Facebook login email, without losing all my friends/contents/updates? If so, will it let me re-use that original email address for a brand new Facebook account?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to the settings tab, add your email address to the list of email addresses, verify your address and delete the address of your wife. Voilà you have a new login address.

This works because you can use any of your email address associated with Facebook for login.

Comment: I do believe there is also an option to change the primary address in that list.

Answer (score 2):

Have you saved your Facebook password? If so you can login to your Facebook account and change the email address in your **Account Settings**:

[image]