# I can't get to my Facebook

Tags: facebook

My old Email address was `casper777@???cast.net` and I changed to an new internet services but not I can not get to my Facebook account with my new internet so I need someone to go in my Facebook account and change it to my new `casper777@wild???.net`

Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/867/29140